# Strange behavior of eval() breaks unittest

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have been prototyping and not minding the low-quality code that assigned a variable which took it's value from calling eval() on argv, which in turn picked up it's value in external file containing API keys. To my surprise it badly crashed unit testing (None of them even ran).

Here is the code snippet which I believe to be the culprit:

```
from sys import argv
from apikeys import *


def setKey(the_key=DCK):
    global CK
    CK = the_key # Currently used key

if len(argv) == 1:
    print('---Executing script. Enter optional arguments if you wish to use special API keys.---')
    setKey()
elif len(argv) > 1:
    setKey(eval(argv[1]))

TOKEN = rget(DOMAIN+'signin', params={'key':CK}).json['response']['token']
PARAMS = {'signature':TESTSIG, 'token':TOKEN}

# Rest of the code uses unittests which rely on PARAMS.
```

So I pass one of the variables containing key as it's value to test my script, it produces the following traceback:

```
[gp@imdev1 dv1/tests]# python 2test_api2.py ANDROID_FILMS_KEY
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "2test_api2.py", line 604, in <module>
    unittest.main()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/unittest2/main.py", line 97, in __init__
    self.parseArgs(argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/unittest2/main.py", line 152, in parseArgs
    self.createTests()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/unittest2/main.py", line 161, in createTests
    self.module)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/unittest2/loader.py", line 148, in loadTestsFromNames
    suites = [self.loadTestsFromName(name, module) for name in names]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/unittest2/loader.py", line 142, in loadTestsFromName
    raise TypeError("don't know how to make test from: %s" % obj)
TypeError: don't know how to make test from: 9b269ac759211de6b3c8b238bd758ccf
```

9b269ac759211de6b3c8b238bd758ccf is basically the result of running eval(ANDROID_FILMS_KEY) and running setKey function in a separate script correctly assigns the API key to CK as string '9b269ac759211de6b3c8b238bd758ccf'

The kicker is as follows: When CK and PARAMS are used in classes containing methods that should be unit-tested Python surprisingly raises the bizarre exception which supposedly tells that unittest doesn't consider 9b269ac759211de6b3c8b238bd758ccf a string?

Comment: You're using `eval` to get a local variable? How about `locals()[variable]`?

Comment: @katrielalex: The question is not about how to rewrite this code for it to work, that is trivial. It's more like "why unittest can't handle eval() correctly?"

Answer (score 1):

The `unittest2` loader *also* inspects `sys.argv`, to let you limit the modules loaded for testing [from the command line](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/unittest2.shtml#command-line-behaviour).

What happens here is that the loader is looking for a test module named `9b269ac759211de6b3c8b238bd758ccf`.

You'll have to manipulate `sys.argv` from your unittest instead; it's a standard python list that you can alter. Alternatively, create a `main(args)` function that, by default, you call with `sys.argv[1:]`:

```
def main(args):
    if not args:
        print('---Executing script. Enter optional arguments if you wish to use special API keys.---')
        setKey()
    else:
        setKey(eval(args[0]))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

and now you can test `main()` with different arguments without having to rely on passing arguments to your test script.

Comment: Where does it look for a test module named 9b269ac759211de6b3c8b238bd758ccf? in unittest's site-packages or the dir where the executed script is?

Comment: @GSP: I guess it looks at the python module path (which includes the local directory). Note that it looks for a `load_tests` function in the module (if that's what you passed on the command line).